# How to restrict/deny access to a resource group for a specific user in azure?

Tags: azure

Through the portal is there anyway we can restrict the user access to a resource group, that ie the should be unable to access the resource group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly create a deny assignment. As in the Portal if you go to the resource group, Click on "Access Control (IAM)" -> "Deny assignments", it is mentioned that "**At this time, the only way you can add your own deny assignments is by using Azure Blueprints.**"

[image]

A deny assignment gets created when you select a blueprint lock type, this tutorial shows how a deny assignment is created:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/tutorials/protect-new-resources

Additional information about blueprint locks can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/concepts/resource-locking#how-blueprint-locks-work

Comment: Thanks, this did provide and insight in how to handle the issue,

Comment: Please mark this as Answer if this was useful.